# How to include Qthread library in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qthread

I am trying to `#include<QThread>` in my `C++` question but it seems that the library is not downloaded. Where can I get it from and how can I add it to Visual Studio?

Comment: You need to install Qt and then link against Qt libraries. If you just need a thread, use `std::thread` and `#include <thread>`

Comment: Where should install the Qt libraries from?

Comment: C'mon, Google is way faster than me. https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/